# analyticity of complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on the domain $\mathbb{D}=\{ z:|z|<1\}.$ I am trying to check analyticity of the function $f{(\bar z)}.$ Please check what i had tried so far and help me. $$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y),  f(\bar{z})=u(x,-y)+iv(x,-y)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)$$ Now for $f(\bar{z})$ to be analytic we must have $$\phi_{x}(x,y)=\psi_{y}(x,y)\Longrightarrow u_{x}(x,-y)=-v_{y}(x,-y).$$ Aging since $f$ is analytic we must have $u_{x}(x,y)=v_{y}(x,y).$ Therefore we have $u_{x}(x,-y)=-v_{y}(x,-y)$ and $u_{x}(x,y)=v_{y}(x,y).$ Therefore$$u_{x}(x,y)=v_{y}(x,y)$$ and $$u_{x}(x,y)=-v_{y}(x,y)$$ Which gives $u_{x}=0$ and $u_{y}=0$(by using the second condition of C-R equations). Now can i say that if  $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ then $f(\bar{z})$ is analytic iff $f$ is a constant fuction? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? (If the gradient of a function vanishes on a connected open set, then the function must be constant.)

Comment: am i right or not? my result about $f(\bar{z})$ is right or not?

Comment: i don't know about gradient. Please check whether my result is right or not.